# Reverse Proxy Httpd Nodejs Pm2

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-ec2, pm2

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy to a Node.Js Express web server. Basically I'm trying to redirect any traffic coming to `mywebsite.com` and have httpd redirect them to node.js app endpoints. So if I would do `mywebsite.com/test` then it would run the /test function in my node app.

I'm running on EC2 (Amazon Linux 2 AMI)

My backend is at:

```
/home/ec2-user/mywebsite/mywebsite_backend/dist
```

I'm running the with `pm2`, which is a monitoring software for node.

Here's the configuration to /etc/httpd/conf.d/mywebsite.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mywebsite.com
  ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /home/ec2-user/mywebsite/mywebsite_backend/dist http://localhost:8055/
  ProxyPassReverse /home/ec2-user/mywebsite/mywebsite_backend/dist http://localhost:8055/
  ErrorLog /etc/httpd/conf.d/error.log
  CustomLog /etc/httpd/conf.d/custom.log combined
  DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/mywebsite/mywebsite_backend/dist

</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to open: `https://mywebsite.com` from a browser I get apache testpage.

When I try https: [https://mywebsite.com/test'](https://mywebsite.com/test%27) I get "Not Found". I'm guessing that this is because there's no :443 virtualhost?

When I try http aka non-secure: http://mywebsite.com I get "Forbidden".

Edit1: It seems that Apache is by default looking in `/var/www/html`. I added a index.html page there and now I can see it when visiting mywebsite.com.

Edit2:
When doing `curl http://localhost:8055/test` on the server the response is:

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

When doing `curl https://localhost:8055/test` on the server the response is:

> curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target
> host name 'localhost' More details here:
> https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could
> not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this
> situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned
> above.

I've made the SSL certificates for my express server with Let's encrypt and I'm pointing to the generated files in my code and it works locally, but it seems I have a problem with SSL with apache?

Edit3:

curl -k http://localhost:8055/test

Does not work.

I've tried now pingin my node app with

curl -k https://localhost:8055/test

It works.

Edit4: Looking at the error logs `/etc/httpd/conf.d/error.log` it seems that there are permission problems with the code being in `/home` directory. I will move it to `/var/www/html/`

Comment: Your ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse are incorrect. Try changing the first part to just `"/"`.

Comment: I tested this but I now get a message "The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request"

Comment: Is your Node server running and responding correctly? If you test with `curl http://localhost:8055/test` does do what you expect? And yes, you will need to access over HTTP unless you set up HTTPS, which you can do separately in your ssl.conf.

Comment: Seems like a problem with SSL. I've edited my answer. @ZacAnger

Comment: I would advise terminating at the proxy, not in your server. Try hitting your server with curl over HTTP and configuring ssl.conf. Your cert won't with `localhost` because you provisioned it with some other domain, but you could use `curl -k` to ignore those errors, for testing.

Comment: Seems like I can only access the app with https, curl -k https://localhost:8055 works. It makes sense since the express app is initialized with https options.